# Java VM signals

Tags: unix, jvm, signals

I have a java process this is getting a signal shutdown. It is one of these SIGTERM, SIGINT, SIGHUP since the shutdown hook is running..

I can't figure out why we are getting the signal. The process runs on ubuntu and I can't find anything in dmesg to indicate the OS sent the signal.

Is there anywhere else that these messages would go? Are there any tools I can attach to the PID to get information about the signal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know the process shuts down *because of the signal*?

Comment: We found that it was a heap OOM error. To answer you question @apangin the shutdown hooks executed. So I know there as a signal.

Comment: No, shutdown hooks are executed on VM exit, which may occur not only because of a signal. In particular, a call to `System.exit()` or a death of all non-daemon threads (your case) will also lead to execution of shutdown hooks.

Comment: In my answer I stated that we found an OOM error in syslog. But yes it wasn’t a signal to shutdown. The vm existed because it couldn’t allocate more memory

Answer (score 0):

So I found the OOM message in the syslog. I was expecting it to be in dmesg. My mistake